# Qt 5.3: Accessing/returning/calling checkboxes that are created dynamically(?)

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, function, checkbox

So I have reached my ceiling of knowledge when it comes to Qt and C++ in general I guess. I am creating check boxes in a QScrollArea based off the input from a QComboBox. Depending on the value selected in the QComboBox, a specific number of check boxes are created. Once I created those check boxes, I am having a problem understanding how to interact (in my case, simply check to see if they are checked or not) with them outside of the function they are being created and called in. I know how to work with them if the buttons were static, but since the check boxes are dynamic (is that the right word?) and can change, I don't know what to do. Below is a little snippet of code on how the check boxes are created. If I now want to simply check if any of the boxes are checked, how do I do that. Can I "return" or "call" the created check boxes in another function somehow? I know I'll simply need to loop through the array and check, I just simply don't know how to get the array of check boxes into another function or how to return them in the function below.

Thanks for the help!

```
void MyProgram::create_checkboxes(QString opnum)
{
QWidget* MDAcheckboxes = new QWidget(ui->MDA);
QVBoxLayout* MDAlayout = new QVBoxLayout(MDAcheckboxes);
QCheckBox *MDAmycheckBox[9];
QList<QString> boxes;

if (opnum == "640")
{
    boxes << "16-1" << "16-2";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
    MDAmycheckBox[i] = new QCheckBox(MDAcheckboxes);
    MDAmycheckBox[i]->setText(boxes[i]);
    MDAlayout->addWidget(MDAmycheckBox[i]);
    }
    ui->MDA->setWidget(MDAcheckboxes);
}
else if (opnum == "645")
{
    boxes << "13-01"<<"13-2"<<"13-3"<<"13-4"<<"13-5";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    MDAmycheckBox[i] = new QCheckBox(MDAcheckboxes);
    MDAmycheckBox[i]->setText(boxes[i]);
    MDAlayout->addWidget(MDAmycheckBox[i]);
    }
    ui->MDA->setWidget(MDAcheckboxes);
}
else if (opnum == "650")
{

    boxes << "13-6"<<"13-7"<<"13-8"<<"13-9"<<"13-10"<<"13-11"<<"13-12"<<"13-13"<<"13-14";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
    MDAmycheckBox[i] = new QCheckBox(MDAcheckboxes);
    MDAmycheckBox[i]->setText(boxes[i]);
    MDAlayout->addWidget(MDAmycheckBox[i]);
    }
    ui->MDA->setWidget(MDAcheckboxes);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `checkBoxes` should have a parent. In this case you will be able to find it with `findChildren`. It also can be done without `groupBox` if you sure that app has no any other checkboxes and `findChildren` will not return you checkboxes which you don't need.

Try this:

```
QList<QCheckBox *> allButtons = ui->groupBox->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();
qDebug() <<allButtons.size();
for(int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); ++i)
{
    if(allButtons.at(i)->isChecked())
        qDebug() << "Use" << allButtons.at(i)->text()<< i;//or what you need
}
```

In general case:

```
QList<QCheckBox*> allButtons = parentOfCheckBoxes->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();
```

Moreover `findChildren` allows you to find children with special `objectName` which can be useful in some cases. Note that you can set the same `objectName` to the different objects.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren

Comment: Does this code not work with ScrollArea? Why must I use groupBox? This definitely helps me though, thank you.

Comment: @Gundown64 You must not, as I said in my answer it should has a parent, parent can be ScrollArea ,groupBox or, another widget, choose the best for your task. In your case the pareint is: `MDAcheckboxes` and `ui->MDA` is a parent for `MDAcheckboxes`

Comment: @Gundown64 I removed groupBox from my answer, so now it will not confuse.